# how to remove spaced and empty string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var test = ["", "A Sample PDF.pdf", " ", "file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg", " "]
```

expected o/p : `["A Sample PDF.pdf","file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg"]`

I have tried as :

1. split by `'"'` (delimiter as `"`)
2. replace spaced strings to empty and then `arr.filter(Boolean)`

Hope there would an easy understandable way to do this , any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```js
var test = ["", "A Sample PDF.pdf", " ", "file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg", " "];

var newT = [];

for(var ind = 0; ind < test.length; ind++){
    if((test[ind].trim()).length > 0){
        newT.push(test[ind]);
    }
}

console.log(newT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var test = ["", "A Sample PDF.pdf", " ", "file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg", " "]

var filteredData = test.filter(i => {
  return i.replace(/ /g, "").length > 0
})

console.log(filteredData);
```